# Insert dates from textbox without error if a date is missing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion

I have two textboxes and containing dates. I want to convert text to date and insert it into a SQL database. If the user didn't enter the date, an error occurs. How do I prevent the error from occurring?

```
     try
        {

            DateTime abc,bsd;
            abc = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
            bsd = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = Scout_DHQ_Manager.Properties.Settings.Default.constring;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (dt,dt2) VALUES('"+abc +"','"+bsd+"')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Details of a new unit is successfully added", " Successfully Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erroe Occure in Connection.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Comment: what error occurs to you?

Comment: Validate empty textbox before execute the query and force the user to enter date...

Comment: some dates are not mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have some kind of validation on your input. If it doesn't look like a date, throw an error.

You can use [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) for this.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();

if(DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out date))
{
    //The text is a valid date
    //Insert it
}
```

If you need a specific format you can use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You might also consider using [parametrized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) as writing code like this will leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: As the values are DateTime variables, in *this case* there is no sql injection problem. But you are right, building sql commands directly from user input is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @HansKesting You are absolutely correct, totally missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Some points:

- Use parameters to shield you from formatting issues (is it DMY or MDY format?). In *this particular case* you don't have a sql injection problem, but you would have it if you used string values from user input directly.
- Make sure those date columns are nullable in your database table.
- Make sure the `abc` and `bsd` variables are of type `Nullable<DateTime>` (or `DateTime?`, which is the same).
- Use `Convert.ToDateTime` only when there is content in that textbox (and catch errors): empty textbox = null date.

Answer (score 1):

Change code like below

```
        DateTime? abc, bsd;
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
            abc = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
        else
            abc = null;
        if (textBox2.Text != "")
            bsd = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text);
        else
            bsd = null;
```

Comment: Parametrized queries are the best way to do this... How you will pass `null` to SqlCommand?

Comment: yes it is better option but you can able to pass null value in sql parameter like - myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bsd",(bsd == null) ? DBNull.Value : bsd);

Answer (score 1):

Keep these things in mind:

- Use parameters in your queries
- Use sensible name for your varables
- Make check to see if values are not null when requesting input from user
- When using quotes in a query sql cast var to string

Considering the above try:

```
try
     {    
       string date1=textBox1.Text;
       string date2= textBox2.Text;
       if (date1!=null)&&((date2!=null)
        {
          date1=DateTime.TryParse(date1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
          date2=DateTime.TryParse(date2).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
          using (con)
          {
           con.ConnectionString = Scout_DHQ_Manager.Properties.Settings.Default.constring;
           con.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd;
           cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (dt,dt2) VALUES(@dt1,@dt2)", con);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", date1);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2", date2);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
           }                   
         }            
            else
            {
              MessageBox.Show("Please Fill in both Textboxes");
            }
         }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erroe Occure in Connection.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```

**EDIT :**

changing your textBoxes to `DateTimePicker` control, might result in better functionality (you will never have null values) if you stick with textBoxes in your else block you can set in you parameter:

```
 parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Brother, the problem is some user don't want to enter the dates, then how can i set the field as blank

Comment: @BlueBurnIndia, maybe my edit helps

Comment: Yes. Brother. Its Working with DBNull.Value. Thank you so much